# How to change selected option value when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Change option  value when Button **Click**

```html
<button class="btn1">clickme1</button>
<button class="btn2">clickme2</button>

<select>
    <option value="1">changevalue1</option>
    <option value="2">changevalue2</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/3L78v8zg/1/)

Comment: Where is your attempt? What's wrong with google? Any purpose for `CSS` tag?

Comment: where is your first step in programming code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Updated JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L78v8zg/2/)

```
$('#dynamicChange').val('1').trigger('change');

$('#dynamicChange').val('2').trigger('change');
```

Comment: It changes value but selected value is the default one

Comment: at the moment this is one of the few choices that is compatible with mobile devices.